# Terminology: Linear 'programming'

Tags: terminology, linear-programming

What is the origin of the term 'programming' in 'linear programming'? It is not obvious to me why this should be called a type of programming.

Comment: It is about *planning*, i.e. finding a "pre-written" (pro-gramma) plan.

Comment: Some of the history and origin of the terminology could be found at [globopt.dsi.unifi.it/gol/Seminari/DeLeone2008.pdf](http://globopt.dsi.unifi.it/gol/Seminari/DeLeone2008.pdf)

Comment: Per my linear algebra book (in which linear programming is touched upon), the term predates computers and computer programming.  Rather, it just refers to a plan that is written down... (fyi)

Comment: This really isn't a question about mathematics.  Perhaps the folk at [english.se] would be more helpful.